# Calculating energy change for calcium carbonate decomposition

Tags: energy, enthalpy

The $\Delta H^0$ for the decomposition of $\ce{CaCO3(s)}$ is $178.3~\mathrm{kJ/mol}$ at $25~\mathrm{^\circ C}$ and $1.000~\mathrm{atm}$. What is the $\Delta E$ for the decomposition process?

$$\ce{CaCO3(s) -> CaO(s) + CO2(g)}$$

I'm really not sure how to get from $\Delta H^0$ to $\Delta E$. I'm not sure if the formula $\Delta H=\Delta E+P\Delta V$ is meant to be used. I know if pressure is constant — as it appears to be in this question — $\Delta H=q$. And I also know the equation $\Delta E=q+w$. As there is no work ($w$) being done, does that just mean $\Delta E=q=\Delta H=178.3~\mathrm{kJ}$? I may be extremely off track here, really not sure.

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.‎

Comment: This is not a homework question - I'm no longer a student. I'm revising my uni chemistry to sit the gamsat test (Australian medical admissions test). I'm just not too sure where to start with this question - what formula do I even use? Thanks!

Comment: Basically any question with the wording your question has is considered homework; it needn't be literally one. Self-study questions, puzzles etc. also count as homework. Don't worry, they're not banned. But, we require a minimal effort. You can just tell us what you did that didn't get answers. We'll take it from there. What do you know about $\Delta H$ or $\Delta E$? Please [edit] your question and add the details.

Comment: Ok no worries. Sorry this is the first time I've ever used this site :)

Comment: @Nilay Please **do not** randomly add `\ce{...}` to every MathJax equation. It is meant **only** for chemicals and *chemical* equations. It is **not** supposed to be used to format units in upright type; use `\mathrm{...}` around the unit for this.

Comment: Would people mind sharing some insight into the question, rather than worrying about the wording or formatting? Thanks...